# How to delete array elements that end with 1?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I need to remove all array elements that have the `name` field ending with `1`.

**Input:**

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "data": {
    "code": "abc123",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "exp1"
      },
      {
        "name": "exp2"
      },
      {
        "name": "exp11"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Desired output:**

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "data": {
    "code": "abc123",
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "exp2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

---

**My attempt:**

```
jq 'del(.data.items[] | select(.name | endswith("1")))' input
```

Which results in `Invalid path expression`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this `jq` filter:

```
jq '.data.items|=map(select(.name|endswith("1")|not))' file
```

This replace `.data.items` with the a new array having objects whose `name`s don't end with `1`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your attempt will work with recent versions of jq (that is, more recent than version 1.5).
2. Yet another variant (perhaps the most concise robust alternative):

   `.data.items|=map(select(.name|test("[^1]$")))`